# Performance issue while displaying last "n" items in Windows Forms ListBox (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

I am using ListBox to display last "n" items (say 10000) for a Real Time application. I am receiving around 10 lines of data for a fraction of second from a system. Once ListBox line reaches "n" (say 10000), I am manually removing first 10  items (using While loop) and adding newly received 10 items (using While loop). As data input traffic is more, UI is freezing while performing delete/add operation. Application is working fine if we comment delete operation. Means if we perform only add operation, application is working fine for more than 1 lack lines.

So kindly share the suggestion:

1. How can we display only last "n" items in UI?
2. Any other option is available other than ListBox?
3. Is there any LINQ query available to delete first few items (say 10) from list box so that delete operation will be faster.

Development Environment:

Windows Forms application with Visual Studio 2015

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Hari.

Comment: Could you share your delete code

Answer (score 1):

10000 items in an anything is a bit wasteful, there are controls around that use virtualization. I.e they only maintain whats needed to show

However you might want to take a look at the [ListBox.BeginUpdate Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.beginupdate?view=netframework-4.7.2), it might help with the deletes

> Maintains performance while items are added to the ListBox one at a
>   time by preventing the control from drawing until the EndUpdate()
>   method is called.

Comment: In a `BeginUpdate` / `EndUpdate` sequence, adding 10,000 strings to a ListBox (just made a 64bit run-time measure) takes 35~42ms. `RemoveAt(0)` 10 elements 2~3ms. In a Task `.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { }` you wouldn't even notice it. But you could throw in one of your mythical BenchMarks!

Comment: @Jimi haha mythical, splendiferous benchmarks, was it any faster with begin update? then without?

Comment: 3.1x ~ 3.4x times faster. One column; with multiple columns it's much faster, more or less the same time (I didn't check whether it uses BeginUpdate/EndUpdate internally in this case). Running from the .exe, Release mode, 64bit.